# Asymptotic approximation of the binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series

Asymptotic approximation of the binomial coefficient
\begin{equation}
\binom{-1/2}{m}
\end{equation}
What is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the gamma function?

Comment: How do you define negative, rational arguments to the factorial function?  Probably with the Gamma function, but just making sure.

Comment: Yes, $\Gamma$ is defined on $\Bbb C \setminus \{n \in \Bbb Z \; | \; n \leq 0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$${-1/2 \choose n}=\frac{1}{n!}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)...\left(-\frac{1}{2}-n+1\right)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{1\cdot3\cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)}{2^n}=\frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{n!^2 \cdot 4^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n} {2n \choose n}$$

Now use either [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) or [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) to prove that

$${-1/2 \choose n} \sim \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n \pi}}$$